# How to put a button in a table and have it functional too?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

while creating a table to display the data of each cookie clicker upgrade, I would like a button for each upgrade in the table so that I can press it and the upgrade would be upgraded. I thought that my current code would work but for some reason the button is not able to be clicked.

I've tried different ways of creating buttons, and also tried moving the button to the java script code.

```js
    let cookies = 0;
    let clickerValue = 1;
    let clickerCost = 10;
    let clickerAmount = 1;
    let grandmaValue = 2;
    let grandmaCost = 100;
    let grandmaAmount = 0;

    function setupCookies() {
    document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIES";
    displayValue();
    displayCost();
    displayAmount();
    }

    function displayValue() {
    document.getElementById("clickerValue").innerHTML = clickerValue;
    document.getElementById("grandmaValue").innerHTML = grandmaValue;

    }

    function displayCost() {
    document.getElementById("clickerCost").innerHTML = clickerCost;
    document.getElementById("grandmaCost").innerHTML = grandmaCost;
    }

    function displayAmount() {
    document.getElementById("clickerAmount").innerHTML = clickerAmount;
    document.getElementById("grandmaAmount").innerHTML = grandmaAmount;


    }

    function clicker() {
    cookies += clickerValue;
    if (cookies === 1) {
        document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIE";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIES";
    }
    }

    function clickerIncrease() {
    if (cookies >= clickerCost) {
        cookies -= clickerCost;
        clickerAmount += 1;
        setupCookies();
    }
    else {
        alert("you dont have enough cookies");
    }
    }

    function grandma() {
    cookies += grandma
    }

    function grandmaIncrease() {
    if (grandmaAmount >= 1) {
        setInterval(grandma(), 1000);
        document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIES";
    }
    }
```

```css
    .parade {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    }

    .shade {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: chocolate;
    padding: 20px;
    }

    .shade:hover {

    }

    .shade:active {

    }

    .cartier {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .cartierButtons {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkred;
    background-color: grey;
    }

    .cartierButtons:hover {
    color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cookie Clicker</title>
    </head>

    <script src = "cookie%20clicker.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cookie%20clicker.css"/>

    <body onload = "setupCookies()">
    <table class = "cartier">
        <tr>
            <th>UPGRADES</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
            <th>COST</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="cartierButtons"                                                                                             
                 onclick="clickerIncrease()">CLICKER</a></td>
            <td id = "clickerValue"></td>
            <td id = "clickerCost"></td>
            <td id = "clickerAmount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GRANDMA</td>
            <td id = "grandmaValue"></td>
            <td id = "grandmaCost"></td>
            <td id = "grandmaAmount"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class = "parade" id = "mulah"></div>
    <a href="#" class="shade" onclick="clicker()">COOKIES</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The button shows up as intended, however, I'm not able to click it and perform that function.

Comment: Please post the definition of `clickerIncrease`.

Comment: function clickerIncrease() {
    if (cookies >= clickerCost) {
        cookies -= clickerCost;
        clickerAmount += 1;
        setupCookies();
    }
    else {
        alert("you dont have enough cookies");
    }
}

Comment: If you dont add your whole javascript functions and variables, its really hard to reproduce your problem.

Comment: sorry i just included my entire code to make everything more clear

Comment: Please evaluate on what is going wrong, i see the counter going up, what else would be expected behaviour?

Comment: the button in the table is not able to be clicked

Comment: alright give me a sec

Comment: So much repetitive code and the names are ridiculous so I can't even understand by context. What exactly do you expect to happen when a button(s) are clicked?

Comment: the word clicker from the table is a button, i expect that button to work, however i believe that it doesn't work because it is in a table.

Comment: @LukaPopovic I have added a new answer. A div was overlapping your button. Please accept or upvote if the answer solver your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant click on your button inside your table, because the div with the id "mulah" is overlapping your table. You can see this when inspecting your element inside your browser. 
Just make the div not overlap your button.

```
 #mulah{
   width: 50px;
  }
```

```js
let cookies = 0;
    let clickerValue = 1;
    let clickerCost = 10;
    let clickerAmount = 1;
    let grandmaValue = 2;
    let grandmaCost = 100;
    let grandmaAmount = 0;

    function setupCookies() {
    document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIES";
    displayValue();
    displayCost();
    displayAmount();
    }

    function displayValue() {
    document.getElementById("clickerValue").innerHTML = clickerValue;
    document.getElementById("grandmaValue").innerHTML = grandmaValue;

    }

    function displayCost() {
    document.getElementById("clickerCost").innerHTML = clickerCost;
    document.getElementById("grandmaCost").innerHTML = grandmaCost;
    }

    function displayAmount() {
    document.getElementById("clickerAmount").innerHTML = clickerAmount;
    document.getElementById("grandmaAmount").innerHTML = grandmaAmount;


    }

    function clicker() {
    cookies += clickerValue;
    if (cookies === 1) {
        document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIE";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIES";
    }
    }

    function clickerIncrease() {
    if (cookies >= clickerCost) {
        cookies -= clickerCost;
        clickerAmount += 1;
        setupCookies();
    }
    else {
        alert("you dont have enough cookies");
    }
    }

    function grandma() {
    cookies += grandma
    }

    function grandmaIncrease() {
    if (grandmaAmount >= 1) {
        setInterval(grandma(), 1000);
        document.getElementById("mulah").innerHTML = cookies + " COOKIES";
    }
    }
```

```css
.parade {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    }

    .shade {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: chocolate;
    padding: 20px;
    }

    .shade:hover {

    }

    .shade:active {

    }

    .cartier {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .cartierButtons {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkred;
    background-color: grey;
    }

    .cartierButtons:hover {
    color: red;
    }

  #mulah{
   width: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cookie Clicker</title>
    </head>

    <script src = "cookie%20clicker.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cookie%20clicker.css"/>

    <body onload = "setupCookies()">
    <div>
    <table class = "cartier">
        <tr>
            <th>UPGRADES</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
            <th>COST</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="cartierButtons"                                                                                             
                 onclick="clickerIncrease()">CLICKER</a></td>
            <td id = "clickerValue"></td>
            <td id = "clickerCost"></td>
            <td id = "clickerAmount"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GRANDMA</td>
            <td id = "grandmaValue"></td>
            <td id = "grandmaCost"></td>
            <td id = "grandmaAmount"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class = "parade" id = "mulah" ></div>
    <a href="#" class="shade" onclick="clicker()">COOKIES</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: no problem. in most browsers you can "inspect elements", so you will find errors like this more quickly.